# Extracting common exception handling code of several methods in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have some private method in a class which has equal exception handling. Their body code raises equal exception types and the code handling is the same.

```
private void method1() {
  try {
     //make_the_world_a_better_place
  }
  catch(IOException ioe) {
     // ...
  }
}

private boolean method2(String str) {
  try {
     //make_a_cheesecake
  }
  catch(IOException ioe) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Which is the best way to externalize the common exception handling, so when I make a change in the exception handling code of one of the methods the change will propagate to other methods? Template Method pattern would be handy in this situation, but I don't want go deep into the class hierarchy.

EDIT: There are several catch clauses, not only one like in the example.

Answer (score 6):

Create an interface:

```
public interface Executor {

  void exec() throws Exception;

}
```

---

in your class:

```
checkForExceptions(new Executor() {

  @Override
  public exec() throws Exception {

    method1();

  }

});

private void checkForExceptions(Executor ex) {
  try {
    ex.exec();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    /// handling
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! Your solution is the object-oriented alternative to the Template Method. But really I don't want to introduce new hierarchy of classes for such a simple (?) task? Is it possible to reuse exception handling code in the same class? I see that I need to use anonymous classes, but anyway need to introduce new interface.

Comment: I afraidno, at least in java 6. If there were lambda(waiting for jdk 7), you wouldn't need any interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct is good - DRY is a good thing.  But don't do this.  Your code will be harder to read.

Make sure your catch blocks are really handling the exception and not just swallowing it.  If your class isn't providing remediation, I'd say it'd be better to throw it and let clients figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `handleException(IOException ioe)` method which they both call.

Comment: I was thinking for a try-catch-handling at one place and the method's logic between them, but I guess the world then would be too perfect. Actually I have several catch clauses in the methods...

Comment: I catch the different exceptions and throw custom runtime exception with different messages supplied. What will happen if this changes in future? Anyway my question is general, I am curious to know how it is possible to do that in Java.

Comment: My approach would be to not throw custom exceptions, just pass up the original exceptions and avoid lots of catch blocks here and there.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the checked exceptions thrown by the methods.

Comment: Can you explain why?  Perhaps this is something you don't need to worry about. ;)

Comment: It is my decision. The client code will not be forced to handle these exceptions. It may not have enough knowledge, how to handle them or it will be not interested handling them anyway.

Comment: Another way to handle this genericly is to provide a Proxy.  This way to can wrap the exceptions of every method in just one place with an invocation handler.  They are reasonly efficient depending on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, it similar to the approach of dynamic proxies in Java. But I need to write my own implementation of the proxy class instead. Thanks for your comments. It seems I need to depend on a design pattern to resolve my issue than to any language-level feature.

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking for a try-catch-handling at one place and the method's logic between them, but I guess the world then would be too perfect. Actually I have several catch clauses in the methods.